Query data from views with WHERE statement
I have two tables in my Databricks Unity Catalog.

Data of trips, approximately 30.000 rows.




TripID
Client
Location
Start
End
...




ABC
client1
loc1
2023-01-01T00:00:00
2023-01-01T08:00:00
...


DEF
client1
loc2
2023-01-01T10:00:00
2023-01-01T15:00:00
...




Wide table of metrics data




Timestamp
sensor1
sensor2
...




01-01-2023T02:01:01
val1
val2
...


01-01-2023T02:01:02
val3
val4
...



We want to combine these 2 tables in a view alike
CREATE VIEW AS my_view
SELECT *
FROM metrics
LEFT JOIN trips ON timestamp BETWEEN start AND end

End users will query this view in their applications via queries alike
SELECT *
FROM my_view
WHERE Client = 'my_client' and Location = 'my_location'

Creating a table instead of a view is not desirable because of data multiplication
My Question is:
Will the whole view be created before filtering on client/location,
or will client/location filtering be executed instantly when the view is queried?

In Databricks, using CREATE VIEW by itself will create a non materialized view.  This view, when executed, will generally behave like the underlying select query.
On the other hand, if you were to use CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW, then the view would be precompiled and persisted on your database.  In this case, selecting from the materialized view would access the already-computed result of the underlying select query.
See here for more information on using materialized views with Databricks.

You can think of a view as the result of a pre-defined query. The query inside the view is executed dynamically every time the view is called. When the end user executes a filtered query on the view, the database optimizer typically attempts to push down the predicate (the filter condition) into the underlying query of the view to minimize the amount of data processed.
You can always check the query plan by running:
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * 
FROM my_view 
WHERE Client = 'my_client' AND Location = 'my_location';

Hope this clears up your question and helps!
